# Unable to find entry point 'glCreateShader' in 'OpenGL32.dll

Tags: c#, opengl, dll, graphics

I am getting the error "Unable to find an entry point named 'glCreateShader' in DLL 'opengl32.dll'." 
 
 Does anyone know what could be causing these errors? 
 
 Here is the class that is causing the error

```
class PixelBlocks
{

    private static ShaderProgram program;

    public static void generateBlock(ref objStructs.Block Block)
    {
        Texture blockTex = Block.Texture;
        VBO<Vector3> square;
        VBO<int> elements;
        float Scale = clientInfo.curScale;
        Matrix4 trans;
        Matrix4 SclFct;

        program = new ShaderProgram(VertexShader, FragmentShader);

        program.Use();
        program["projection_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(0.45f, (float)Program.width / Program.height, 0.1f, 1000f));
        program["view_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.LookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 10), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up));

        program["light_direction"].SetValue(new Vector3(0, 0, 1));
        program["enable_lighting"].SetValue(Program.lighting);

        square = new VBO<Vector3>(new Vector3[] {
            new Vector3(-1, 1, 0),
            new Vector3(1, 1, 0),
            new Vector3(1, -1, 0),
            new Vector3(-1, -1, 0) });
        elements = new VBO<int>(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 }, BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer);

        trans = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(Block.Blk.x, Block.Blk.y, 0));
        SclFct = Matrix4.CreateScaling(new Vector3(Scale, Scale, 0f));

        Block.corners = square;
        Block.elements = elements;
        Block.trans = trans;
        Block.Scale = SclFct;
    }
    public static bool drawBlocks(objStructs.Block[] Blocks)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < Blocks.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Gl.UseProgram(program);

                // set up the model matrix and draw the cube
                program["model_matrix"].SetValue(Blocks[i].trans * Blocks[i].Scale);

                Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(Blocks[i].corners, program, "vertexPosition");

                Gl.BindBuffer(Blocks[i].elements);

                #pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
                Gl.DrawElements(BeginMode.Quads, Blocks[i].elements.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero);
                #pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static string VertexShader = @"
    #version 130
    in vec3 vertexPosition;
    in vec3 vertexNormal;
    in vec2 vertexUV;
    out vec3 normal;
    out vec2 uv;
    uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
    uniform mat4 view_matrix;
    uniform mat4 model_matrix;
    void main(void)
    {
       normal = normalize((model_matrix * vec4(floor(vertexNormal), 0)).xyz);
       uv = vertexUV;
       gl_Position = projection_matrix * view_matrix * model_matrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1);
    }
    ";

    public static string FragmentShader = @"
    #version 130
    uniform sampler2D texture;
    uniform vec3 light_direction;
    uniform bool enable_lighting;
    in vec3 normal;
    in vec2 uv;
    out vec4 fragment;
    void main(void)
    {
       float diffuse = max(dot(normal, light_direction), 0);
float ambient = 0.3;
float lighting = (enable_lighting ? max(diffuse, ambient) : 1);
fragment = lighting * texture2D(texture, uv);
}
";
}
```

I know that's a lot of code but I don't what is causing this error.

I am using this library: https://github.com/giawa/opengl4csharp which is why it's not like any other questions

Graphics: Intel Iris Pro Graphics Experimental Version and Recommended Version both Tried
Processor: Intel i5
IDE: Visual Studio 2015 Community